# NASM convert Binary number to Decimal

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

```
%include "asm_io.inc"

segment .data
msg1 db "Enter a number: ",0
msg2 db "Bad Number! try again. ",0
msg3 db "Enter Decimal value is: ",0

segment .bss
mask resd 1

segment .text
global main

main:
    enter 0,0
    pusha

    mov dword[mask],1
    mov esi,10
    mov ebx,0


input:
    mov eax,msg1
    call print_string
    call read_int
    mov ecx,eax

next:
    cmp eax,0
    je cont
    mov edx,0   
    div esi
    cmp edx,1
    ja error
    jmp next

error:      
    mov eax,msg2
    call print_string
    call print_nl
    jmp input


cont: mov eax,ecx

convert:
    cmp eax,0
    je sof
    mov edx,0
    div esi
    cmp edx,0
    je shift_1
    or ebx,[mask]

shift_1:    
    shl dword[mask],1
    jmp convert

sof:    
    mov eax,msg3
    call print_string
    mov eax,ebx
    call print_int
    call print_nl

    popa 
    leave 
    ret
```

---

The program gets only 1 and 0 and prints its decimal value.
It does not work on more than 10 bits number (i need it to be working on 32 bits number), also it does not work with number that starts with 0 (like 011)
Help pls :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't known what `read_int` do exactly but if it is named accordingly it should read a 32 bit integer from input and return it in `EAX`.
This means that you are requesting the user to input a binary number as a decimal numeral, in order to get a 32 bit number you need 32 decimal digits, so a number of the order of 10^32 or more or less 106 bit.

So this is clearly not the way to go. You need to read the binary digits one at a time, char by char. This way converting from the binary numeral to the number is even easier as you only need to do some shifting!

It also seems that what you want to do is just converting from the binary numeral to the number (i.e. user input binary number and you want its 32 bit value), since the `print_int` function does that work of converting a number to a decimal numeral (ie printing a 32 bit value in decimal).

Here a sample program in NASM (to be linked with GCC) that do what you need. You only need the `get_bin` function. This use C library functions but in a manner similar to your library routines. It also include a routine to print a 32 bit value in decimal, you may skip it.
Use the code in `get_bin` as a reference.

```
BITS 32

GLOBAL _main

EXTERN _getchar
EXTERN _printf

SECTION .data

strInput    db "Input a binary number: ", 0
strInputErr db "Binary number not valid!",0ah, 0
strChar     db "%c", 0h

SECTION .text

_main:

    push strInput
    call _printf 
    add esp, 04h

    call get_bin 
    jnc .input_error

    push eax
    call show_dec

.end:
    ret 

.input_error:
    push strInputErr
    call _printf 
    add esp, 04h

jmp .end 




get_bin:
    push ecx
    push edx

    mov ecx, 20h    ;//32 bit

    xor edx, edx    ;Temp result

.get:
    push edx 
    call _getchar
    pop edx

    cmp al, 0ah
    je .return      ;End early if user press Return

    sub al, 30h     ;ASCII digit -> digit value
    cmp al, 01h     ;Only 0 and 1 allowed
    ja .end         ;Here CF=0, meaning conversion failed

    shr al, 01h     ;Set the CF based on the new digit
    rcl edx, 01h    ;Shift this digit into EDX from the right
loop .get

.return:
    mov eax, edx    ;Return in EAX
    stc             ;CF=1 means conversion ok

.end:
    pop edx
    pop ecx
    ret

;number     
show_dec:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    pushad

    sub esp, 04h 
    mov BYTE [ebp-04h], 0 

    mov ebx, 1000000000d 
    mov eax, DWORD [ebp+08h]
    mov ecx, 10d 

.loop:
    xor edx, edx
    div ebx 

    test al, al
    setnz ah 
    or BYTE [ebp-04h], ah
    setnz ah 
    test cl, cl
    setz ch
    or ch, ah
    jz .continue

    add eax, 30h 

    pushad
    push eax
    push strChar
    call _printf
    add esp, 08h 
    popad 

.continue:
    xor ch, ch 
    mov eax, edx 
    push eax

    mov eax, ebx
    xor edx, edx
    mov ebx, 10d
    div ebx
    mov ebx, eax 
    pop eax
loop .loop

    add esp, 04h 

    popad 

    pop ebp
    ret 04h
```

Please note that by default input from terminal/console is cooked.

Comment: where do I use get_bin function?? Help tnx

Comment: @TalorT I cannot write a drop in replacement code for I don't have your asm_io.inc file, use the code as a template, a guide. `get_bin` ask the user to input a binary number and return it in EAX, it does the work of your code from `call read_int` to the `sof` label.

Comment: what is you mail I will send you the asm_io.inc file

Comment: I know that my program gets only 10 bit binary which is 1023 in decimal I need it to get 32 bit binary

Comment: @TalorT you get only 10 bit because you read a decimal number, with 32 bit you can have only 10 decimal digits (that you treat as binary digits). I'm sorry but I think you are asking help for an homework and it would be unfair to solve it for you. I think the code in this answer is enough to understand and correct the mistakes.